# find the minimum value out of a list or array excluding certain elements

Tags: vba, excel

- I have a list of variables that I need to find the minimum value of and evaluate as candidates to increase a different, related value by 1.
- However variables that are already equal to 100 (as in percent) should not be considered as they cannot be increased beyond 100.

(determination variables are a's, increment values are b's)

```
a1 = 0.5,
a2 = 0.6,
a3 = 0.2,
myArray(0) = a1
myArray(1) = a2
myArray(2) = a3
b1 = 0,
b2 = 10,
b3 = 100
```

**My current code**

```
If b1 = 100 Then
myArray(0) = null (empty, something to remove it from consideration in min function)
End IF
If b2 = 100 Then
myArray(1) = null
End IF
If b3 = 100 Then
myArray(2) = null
End IF
minvalue = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(myArray(0), myArray(1), myArray(2))
'also tried: minvalue = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(myArray)
If minvalue = a1 Then
b1 = b1 +1
Else If minvalue = a2 Then
b2 = b2 +1
Else If minvalue = a3 Then
b3 = b3 +1
End IF
```

I want the code to note that even though a3 is the smallest value, b3 cannot be increased anymore, so the next lowest value is a1, and as such b1 is increased by 1.

This functionality does work in the regular excel spreadsheet. I can make a list of values and then in the cell below them type: `=Min(A1,B1,C1)` where A1 = a1 in my example, and B2 = a2 in my example above, etc. and if I type Null in C1, the min function equates to a1 without problem.

However, when I try to do the same thing in [vba](/questions/tagged/vba), minvalue just keeps equating to 0 whenever an element in myArray is Null.

I have also looked into attempting to manually determine the minimum value with loops, but it is very ugly and I would like to keep the code as clean as possible.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: How about running an autofilter excluding the 100 values and running `application.worksheetfunction.min(columns(1).specialcells(xlcelltypevisible))`?

Comment: none of the variables I'm using are actually in a spreadsheet somewhere, initial data has been read in from a sheet, and results will be written to a different sheet, but everything is being calculated as variables within the code and not elements of a spreadsheet

Comment: are your variables all defined individually? Could you get `arr(1,0)=a1` and `arr(1,1)=b1`?

Comment: not exactly sure what you mean, the a variables have been defined as variant so they may be set to null, which didn't work, the b variables are percentage counters and need not be sorted or put into an array

Comment: I'm thinking you could run a loop and use the looping to determine your min.

Comment: yes, but which syntax would i use to remove a3 from consideration from the minimum looping process, i would like to avoid gimmicks like setting it = 99999...

Comment: Use a 2 D array, where arr(1,1)=0.5, arr(1,2)=0, arr(2,1)=0.6, arr(2,2)=10,arr(3,1)=0.2, arr(3,2)=100, then loop saying for lloop=lbound to ubound, if arr(lloop,2)<>100 and arr(lloop,1)<dMininum then dMinimum=arr(lloop,1) arr(lloop,2)=arr(lloop,2)+1

Answer (score 2):

This uses loops but I would consider this fairly clean code.

```
Sub test()

    Dim a(1 To 3) As Double
    Dim b(1 To 3) As Double
    Dim check(1 To 3) As Boolean
    Dim lowestIndex As Integer
    Dim lowestValue As Double

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer

    a(1) = 0.5
    a(2) = 0.6
    a(3) = 0.2

    b(1) = 0
    b(2) = 10
    b(3) = 100


    'initialize to  everything initially
    For i = 1 To UBound(a)
        If (b(i) >= 100) Then
            check(i) = False
        Else
            check(i) = True
        End If
    Next i


    Dim numbTimesToDoStuff As Integer
    numbTimesToDoStuff = 100

    'go through this process however many times you need
    For i = 1 To numbTimesToDoStuff
        'reset each iteration
        lowestValue = 99999

        'find minimum value and index each time
        For j = 1 To UBound(a)
            If (check(j) = True) Then
                If (a(i) < lowestValue) Then
                    lowestValue = a(i)
                    lowestIndex = i
                End If
            End If

        Next j

        'check if no values were found to be lowest and valid
        If (lowestValue = 99999) Then
            MsgBox ("Error: not checking any values!")
        End If

        'update appropriate "b"
        b(lowestIndex) = b(lowestIndex) + 1
        'check if you've reached 100 and stop future checks
        If (b(lowestIndex >= 100)) Then
            check(lowestIndex) = False
        End If


    Next i



End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Filter` to remove values from your array.

In this case `Filter` is used to remove the `100` values from the array, then `EVALUATE` is used to take the miniumum of the remaining array

```
Sub Test2()
Dim MyArray()
MyArray = Array(900, 112, 100, 122, 196)
MsgBox Evaluate("Min(" & Join(Filter(MyArray, 100, False), ",") & ")")
End Sub
```